# Giving different record set after changing simple SQL query to LINQ query

Tags: sql, linq

I have write the below query in simple SQL, 
I want to change it to use LINQ, I have tried, but my LINQ query and the original SQL statement are giving different record sets.

Simple SQL Query:

```sql
select * 
from Paymentadvices 
where status = 3 
and Id in (select PaymentAdviceId from Approvals where ApprovedById = 13)
```

LINQ:

```cs
var myPaymentAdviceList = from pa in db.PaymentAdvices
                          where pa.Status == 3 
                          join Ap in db.Approvals on pa.Id equals 
                          Ap.PaymentAdviceId
                          where Ap.EmployeeId == 13
                          orderby pa.PaidDate descending
                          select pa;
```

I am not supposed to use join I guess, What should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = db.Approvals.Where( x => x.ApprovalById = 13).PaymentAdviceId;

var b = db.Paymentadvices.Where(x => x.status ==3 && a.Contains(x.Id);
```

`.Contains()` makes the `WHERE IN ()`  , you don't need a join there

```
var a = from a in db.Approvals
        where a.ApprovedById == 3
        select a.PaymentAdviceId;

var b = (from p in db.PaymentAdvices
        where p.Status == 3 &&
        a.Contains(p.Id)
        select p).ToList();
```

those are both linq , the top is just lambda expressions which are commonly used in Linq queries.  I would reccommend that you get used to reading/ writing both styles .  The majority of code you'll come across in lambda style

Comment: you mean you want in a single query??  This is a single query , var a will be defered untill var b is executed , look at the generated sql.

Comment: @user1650894 - and really stack overflow is supposed to be used to help where you're stuck and guide you to finding a solution - that is pretty demanding about the style your answer is in

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like the below would work:

```
var query = from p in db.PaymentAdvices
            where p.Status == 3 && db.Approvals
                .Select(a => a.Id)
                .Where(a => a.ApprovedById == 13)
                .Contains(p.Id)
            select p;
```

Though it's worth noting that @Scott Selby and @axrwkr solutions above are essentially the exact same thing in another form.